# 2017 Moderator Election - We need more candidates!

Tags: discussion, election

In about 3 hours, [the nomination phase of the moderator elections](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election?cb=1) is scheduled to end. However, in order for the election to proceed, it is necessary to have at least one more candidate running than there are slots. This allows for there to be actual voting phases, so that the community can actually show that they support the candidates who are running. Should there not be enough candidates, the nomination phase will instead be extended for another 7 days.

We need leadership to come from within this community, the election can't move forward unless there's enough folks stepping up to take responsibility. Did you consider nominating but decided not to for some reason? Now would be a great time to reconsider!

Comment: I'd have run for the spirit of running, but I'm limited by the rep.

Comment: To be honest, current moderators are doing such a flawless job that I am not sure if we need another moderator.

Comment: @NVZ The rep limit is there to prevent people from running as mod without proper knowledge on that topic. It will be difficult for them to decide whether a question or answer worth keeping and so on.

Comment: @SagarV I'm aware, but thanks. There's only one spot open. I'd have nominated just for the sake of having two candidates. But anyways, thank you.

Comment: @NVZ fyi, the process is, they extended the nomination for 7 more days and if they didn't get 1 more candidate, they will cancel the election

Comment: @SagarV Again, I'm aware of the election stuff. I'd still volunteer to participate any day. :)

Comment: I'm confused. What is the purpose of the election, and how many moderators are to be elected? This doesn't seem to be explained anywhere. I automatically assumed it's just that the term of the current moderators expires, but seeing @Kaveh's comment above (and the fact that none of the current moderators are nominated), I probably misunderstood.

Comment: @Emil, moderators don't have a term, since none of the current moderators said they want to step down, my understanding is that they are adding a new moderator to the current ones.

Comment: @Emil One moderator slot is needed, so at least two candidates are expected to step up. Moderation is a volunteer position - so the important thing is there being willingness to perform the duties. The flag load isn't demanding enough to require an increase in team size but it is generally healthier that the team all be active members of the site, and thus actively available especially should one or more teammates be absent. So we're hunting for some additional active hands

Comment: All right, thank you both.

Comment: Some candidates from previous elections:  [Aaron](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/30/aaron-sterling), [Hsien-Chih](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/1800/hsien-chih-chang-%e5%bc%b5%e9%a1%af%e4%b9%8b), [Neel](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/657/neel-krishnaswami), [Sasho](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/users/4896/sasho-nikolov).

Comment: I hope to run in the next election whenever that might be.  :)

Comment: @MichaelWehar in case you didn't see it: https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2999/2018-potential-moderator-election-community-interest-check

Comment: @BjørnKjos-Hanssen Thank you so much for sharing!!  :)