# 2017 Moderator Election has been cancelled

Tags: discussion, election

We regret to inform that due to insufficient nominating candidates, we are currently terminating the ongoing election here on Theoretical Computer Science Stack Exchange. Thank you to Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen for having stood up as a candidate in this session. However, as [explained previously](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2989/2017-moderator-election-we-need-more-candidates), in order for an election to proceed to voting phases it is required that there is at least one more candidate than there are spaces remaining in the election.

This is important for a variety of reasons. The first is that it allows the election process to proceed in a way that allows candidates to be evaluated before being elected. It also serves to indicate that there are enough people in the community who are willing to handle the responsibilities of overseeing moderation.

---

Theoretical Computer Science is not a site that's particularly in danger of low moderation. There's a healthy number of regular users across most reputation brackets who remain active on the site, still handling general moderation tasks.  The flag load itself isn't particularly large, and the current moderation team has expressed that they aren't overwhelmed by it. However, only one of the current moderators is highly active - while this is sufficient for the current flag load, it is healthier for the site to have multiple active moderators, not only to split even the small loads but also to handle situations where one of the moderators may have more pressing matters to attend.

It could be that now is just not a good time to have hosted an election for this site. The winter holidays are coming up soon, as well, which will mess up with future election timings, so we'll most likely look at some elections coming into the new year.

Comment: Thanks @Bjørn Kjos-Hanssen for running. I hope you consider running again next time there's an election.  Many of the questions in your research area are the type of problems I/we have the most trouble deciding on.

Comment: Yeah, I'll consider it, thanks @LevReyzin