# 2018 Potential Moderator Election Community Interest Check

Tags: discussion, election, moderators

Since the last election, the Community Team's noticed that the bulk of the flag handling's been mostly done by a single moderator.

We have systems in place to remove inactive moderators, but since we always have a minimum of three moderators on the team that removal would be accompanied by an election to have replacements made. As you're probably aware, [this community's last election failed due to lack of candidates](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/q/2990/32595). To avoid finding ourselves in a similar situation again, I'm posting this to try to assess the community members' willingness to step up and nominate themselves, should we decide to hold an election.

Please leave an answer if you'd be willing to run for a moderator position, should we decide to run an election. We're currently planning to start question collection on June 18th, '18.

**NOTE:** This is not an official election nomination thread, just a "pulse check" to get a notion of how many people here would be willing to step up, so you don't have to put up your whole election nomination.

Answer (score 6):

I want to run for election!  :)

Here is a brief explanation for why I would be a successful candidate:

- I am an active member of this community and I check for new posts every weekday
- I am a computer science teacher and researcher (just accepted a position @ Temple University)
- I have prior experience being a moderator for various online communities for software engineering and language learning

Answer (score 4):

I'm interested too

I have >15K reputation (including all moderation privileges) on MathOverflow and a 100% helpful flag record there.

And I developed a couple of TCS-related online games that I'm interested in relating to TCS.stackexchange.

[image: Gamify your Q&A]
[image: Gamify your Q&A]