# 2018 Moderator Election Q&A - Question Collection

Tags: discussion, election

After successful evaluation in [our interest check](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2999/2018-potential-moderator-election-community-interest-check), CSTheory has been scheduled for an election [next week, June 25th](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/election/4). In connection with that, we will be holding a Q&A with the candidates.  This will be an opportunity for members of the community to pose questions to the candidates on the topic of moderation.  Participation is completely voluntary.

> **The purpose of this thread was to collect questions for the questionnaire. The questionnaire is now live, and you may find it [here](https://cstheory.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/3008/2018-moderator-election-qa-questionnaire).**

Here's how it'll work:

- Until the nomination phase, (so, until Monday, June 25th at 20:00:00Z UTC, or 4:00 pm EDT on the same day, give or take time to arrive for closure), this question will be open to collect potential questions from the users of the site. Post answers to this question containing any questions you would like to ask the candidates. Please only post *one question per answer*.
- We, the Community Team, will be providing a small selection of generic questions. The first two will be guaranteed to be included, the latter ones are if the community doesn't supply enough questions. This will be done in a single post, unlike the prior instruction.
- If your question contains a link, please use the syntax of `[text](link)`, as that will make it easier for transcribing for the finished questionnaire.
- This is a perfect opportunity to voice questions that are specific to your community and issues that you are running into at currently.
- At the start of the nomination phase, the Community Team will select **up to 8 of the top voted questions submitted by the community** provided in this thread, to use in addition to the aforementioned 2 guaranteed questions.
- Once questions have been selected, a new question will be opened to host the actual questionnaire for the candidates, typically containing 10 questions in total.
- This is not the only option that users have for gathering information on candidates. As a community, you are still free to, for example, hold a live chat session with your candidates to ask further questions, or perhaps clarifications from what is provided in the Q&A.

If you have any questions or feedback about this process, feel free to post as a comment here.

Answer (score 5):

Why do you want to be a moderator for the cstheory stackexchange community?

Answer (score 5):

When a comment is flagged as 'no longer needed', what criteria will you use to determine whether to keep the comment or to delete it?

Do you lean towards keeping all comments as a record of what has transpired?  Do you learn towards deleting old comments that are no longer making a major contribution? What approach will you take?

Answer (score 3):

Here is a set of general questions, gathered as very common questions asked every election. As mentioned in the instructions, the first two questions are guaranteed to show up in the Q&A, while the others are if there aren't enough questions (or, if you like one enough, you may split it off as a separate answer for review within the community's 8).

- How would you deal with a user who produced a steady stream of valuable answers, but tends to generate a large number of arguments/flags from comments?
- How would you handle a situation where another mod closed/deleted/etc a question that you feel shouldn't have been?

---

- In your opinion, what do moderators do?
- A diamond will be attached to everything you say and have said in the past, including questions, answers and comments. Everything you will do will be seen under a different light. How do you feel about that?
- In what way do you feel that being a moderator will make you more effective as opposed to simply reaching 10k or 20k rep?

Answer (score 3):

I have a bit the impression that part of the reason why the "inactivity" of the moderators came to the attention of SE was the question

[Is Norbert Blum's 2017 proof that $P \ne NP$ correct?](https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/38803/is-norbert-blums-2017-proof-that-p-ne-np-correct)

which attracted some inappropriate content and corresponding flags. Those flags stayed around for a long time before they were handled. But apart from that episode, I never had the impression that cstheory.se would need more active moderators, the community self-moderation felt sufficient.

Should moderators stay inactive as long as the self-moderation of the community works well?